# How to include sub-entity at ASP.Net MVC3 with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

Goog Day!
Can anybody tell how to include sub-entity?
I have the Forum project. The page, when I need to display all posts of topic, every post have Post informatin, User information, but, at that time, I need have information of User's group and User's role.  (I can't attach image (low reputation), so I try to describe tables by words)
**Post:** id, Title, Text, UserId  // Post.UserId = User.Id
**User:** id, Name, RoleId, GroupId  // User.RoleId = RefRole.Id and User.GroupId = RefGroup.id 
**RefGroup:** id, Name 
**RefRole:** id, Name

If I include just User entity I do it like this:

```
    public ActionResult ViewTopic (int id)
    {
        ForumDBE forumDB = new ForumDBE();
        var posts = forumDB.Post.Include("User").ToList();
        return View(posts);
    }
```

But what need I to do, when at **var post** I need to have RoleName (for exapmple Administrator, Moderator, User) and Group Name (for example Good User, Best User, Advicer...) at View like this?

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcForum.Models.Post>

@foreach (var post in Model)
{
    User Name:  @post.User.Name
    User Group: @post.User.RefGroup.Name
    Uset Role:  @post.User.RefRole.Name
}
```

Comment: Have you tried .Include("User").Include("User.RefGroup").Include("User.RefRole"). From memory this works, but I am not 100%, so I'll comment rather than answer.

Comment: in LINQ-to-SQL, once you got the model being with relations between `Users` table & `RefGroups` table for example, it automatically defines a new property in `User` named `RefGroup`. But in EF, I can't help.

Comment: I spent several days searching for an answer ... Thank you, very much! It works!!
    `var posts = forumDB.Post.Include("User").Include("User.RefGroup").Include("User.RefRole").ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Entity Framework 4 default configuration you don't have to use `Include`

```
public ActionResult ViewTopic (int id)
    {
        ForumDBE forumDB = new ForumDBE();
        var posts = forumDB.Post; // or you can use .ToList() but I prefer to use IQueryable
        return View(posts);
    }
```

then

```
@model IQueryable<MvcForum.Models.Post>

@foreach (var post in Model)
{
    User Name:  @post.User.Name
    User Group: @post.User.RefGroup.Name
    Uset Role:  @post.User.RefRole.Name
}
```

It will use lazy loading since you are using `IQueryable` and not `IEnumerable`

Comment: It works `var posts = forumDB.Post.ToList();` too... Thanks to you all for help!!! Thanks!!